# Tensorflow Model restoration issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I keep find the below problem during RNN model restoration in Tensorflow. The model works well but the restoration has an issue. below is my code. What could be the issue. I have deleted and cleaned all the previous session but the same issue persists.

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(logs_path, 
'Multi_Layer_RNN_model.ckpt-499999.meta'))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(logs_path)
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(logs_path))
```

**THE ERROR**

```
InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [105,400] rhs shape= [111,400]
     [[Node: save/Assign_11 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@rnn/lstm_cell/kernel"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](rnn/lstm_cell/kernel/RMSProp_1, save/RestoreV2:11)]]

Caused by op 'save/Assign_11', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\ADMN\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\ADMN\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ADMN\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\ADMN\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  .................
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you have the reason:

```
lhs shape= [105,400] rhs shape= [111,400]
```

It seems that you have differents dimensions of the vector/tensor between neural networks.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the difference on dimension occurred as a results of a difference in batch sizes in two separate session.